# Yosemite 10.10.4 nowhere to set three finger tap to access Dictionary

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, multi-touch, gesture

I'm in OS X, and I bought my mac from one of my friends. He bought this April,2015.

This is my Force touch trackpad. It's come from the fifth in the first picture. I know you may not understand the language but I am sure there is
no three finger tap to look up.

[image]

[image]

I find the three finger to drag in General(the 8th in the third picture)--Mouse/Force Touch trackpad(the fourth picture), but there is no three finger tap to look up, neither.

[image]

[image]

I tried the Better Touch Tool, and it work sometime, but most of the time did not.

I can push the Force Touch trackpad harder to look up the words in Safari, but not three finger tap. And in Chrome, even the push harder not work.

Now I use Command+Control+D to look up words in Chrome, it works, but I really think it is not as easy as three finger tap(I used it in macbook air).

So can anyone tell me how to make it work? or do I need more info for you to understand my question?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find this by myself, and it turn out to be so easy.

According to [this](https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT204352), I find that it's right in the first picture I post in the question and it's in the top of all and default to force touch but can change to three finger tap.